# How to check what features are extracted while training and testing a CNN model for image classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, scientific-computing

I'm using CNN for training and testing images of seeds. I want to know:

- What features are getting extracted at every layer?
- Is there any way to represent it in a graphical or image format?
- How do I define my classifier to extract only specific features?

  ```
  from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
  from keras.models import Sequential
  from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
  from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
  from keras import backend as K


  # dimensions of our images.
  img_width, img_height = 150, 150

  train_data_dir = 'Train_Walnut_Seed/train'
  validation_data_dir = 'Train_Walnut_Seed/validation'
  nb_train_samples = 70
  nb_validation_samples = 9
  epochs = 50
  batch_size = 16

  if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
          input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
  else:
          input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(64))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(1))
  model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

  # this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
          rescale=1. / 255,
          shear_range=0.2,
          zoom_range=0.2,
          horizontal_flip=True)

  # this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
  # only rescaling
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_data_dir,
  target_size=(img_width, img_height),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  class_mode='binary')

  validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
          validation_data_dir,
          target_size=(img_width, img_height),
          batch_size=batch_size,
          class_mode='binary')

  model.fit_generator(
          train_generator,
          steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=validation_generator,
          validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

  model.save('first_try_walnut.h5')
  ```

The above code is for training the classifier using CNN. how to visually represent the output at each layer while training.
Also how to deploy my trained model into a protocolbuffer(.pb) file for using it in my android project

Comment: your question is way to generic - please be more specific about frameworks, existing code, etc.

Comment: thank you for correcting me i will be providing with more details shortly

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way, or at least the best way I know of to extract useful features would be using an autoencoder.
Check out [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) article from the Keras blog.

Cheers,
Gabriel

Comment: maybe you are talking about getting a clearer output with no loss or less loss, but i want to check what output my classifier gives at each layer on giving an image as input.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: do you have any idea in context of my query?

Comment: Yes, but I would have to redirect you to a post since there is quite a bit to talk about in a post here and it is explained in details there. Check [this](http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/convolutional-neural-networks-and-feature-extraction-with-python/) out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably isn't an issue anymore, but I just thought I'd add this in case it's useful to someone else. As the features output by a CNN aren't really human-readable it is difficult to inspect them. One way is to use t-SNE which gives a visual indication of which embedded representations of the images are close to each other. Another way to do this is using a 'heat map' which shows in more detail which parts of an image are activating parts of the CNN. This post has a nice explanation of some of these techniques: http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/

Getting a classifier to focus on certain features is difficult - either you need to change the network architecture or use image pre-processing to accentuate the features you want the network to focus on. I'm afraid I can't really give more details on that.